# Mongoose.js query criteria not working with boolean and object id search

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm seeing some odd behavior with Mongoose 4.11.

The issue is that I'm getting documents returned that I don't think should be. See below for specifics after the code.

(Sorry for the long code snippets... it's tough when talking about DBs cause you need model, data, query, and results, right?)

Here's the model:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
firstName: {
    type: String
},
lastName: {
    type: String
}
groups: [
    {
        name: String,
        members: [
            {
               user: {
                   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
               },
                hasAccepted: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    default: false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
});
```

the query:

```
const query = {
    'groups.members.user':aUserID, // '5a712ca2db684000102e51b7' in this case
    'groups.members.hasAccepted':'false'
};

const fields = 'firstName lastName groups.name';

User.find(query, fields, function(err, result){
    res.send(result);
});
```

and the data set (leaving out unnecessary name and id fields):

```
[
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "name": "Test Group",
            "members": [
                {
                    "user": {
                        "$oid": "5a712ca2db684000102e51b7"
                    },
                    "hasAccepted": false
                },
                {
                    "user": {
                        "$oid": "5a7141fb5b19bb0011e27658"
                    },
                    "hasAccepted": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "name": "Test Group 2",

            "members": [
                {
                    "user": {
                        "$oid": "5a712ca2db684000102e51b7"
                    },
                    "hasAccepted": true
                },
                {
                    "user": {
                        "$oid": "5a7141fb5b19bb0011e27658"
                    },
                    "hasAccepted": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I would expect to get back only the Test Group, and not Test Group 2 because my query is looking only for groups with the user id matched and hasAccepted property false.

However, I'm getting both groups returned.

I've tried a number of thing to confirm that the query is setup correctly otherwise.

For example if I remove the user id I'm looking for from Test Group 2 and  change the query to:

```
const query = {
    'groups.members.user':aUserID, // '5a712ca2db684000102e51b7' in this case
    'groups.name':'Test Group 2'
};
```

I get nothing returned (this confirms it's not an "OR" operator in play)

If I change the query to:

```
const query = {
    'groups.members.hasAccepted':true
};
```

I get only Test Group 2 returned (this confirms my hasAccepted criteria is working)

It's when I add both together that it stops making sense.

(wish I could vote up anyone who reads this far :) )

Anyone have any ideas as to what could be going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$elemMatch` twice as the embedded array depth is 2, to match correct embedded array element,

Query should be

```
const query = {
    groups : {
        $elemMatch : { members : { $elemMatch : {user : aUserID, hasAccepted : false} } }
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow, that works as expected. Thank you so much! I guess I need to do some reading into $elemMatch. My first time working with document dbs after years with SQL.